# python distutils not include the SWIG generated module

Tags: c++, python, swig, rpm, distutils

I am using distutils to create an rpm from my project. I have this directory tree:

```
project/
        my_module/
                 data/file.dat
                 my_module1.py
                 my_module2.py
        src/
            header1.h
            header2.h
            ext_module1.cpp
            ext_module2.cpp
            swig_module.i
        setup.py
        MANIFEST.in
        MANIFEST
```

my `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('my_module._module',
                sources=['src/ext_module1.cpp',
                         'src/ext_module2.cpp',
                         'src/swig_module.i'],
                swig_opts=['-c++', '-py3'],
                include_dirs=[...],
                runtime_library_dirs=[...],
                libraries=[...],
                extra_compile_args=['-Wno-write-strings'])

setup(  name            = 'my_module',
        version         = '0.6',
        author          = 'microo8',
        author_email    = 'magyarvladimir@gmail.com',
        description     = '',
        license         = 'GPLv3',
        url             = '',
        platforms       = ['x86_64'],
        ext_modules     = [module1],
        packages        = ['my_module'],
        package_dir     = {'my_module': 'my_module'},
        package_data    = {'my_module': ['data/*.dat']} )
```

my `MANIFEST.in` file:

```
include src/header1.h
include src/header2.h
```

the `MANIFEST` file is automatically generated by `python3 setup.py sdist`. And when i run `python3 setup.py bdist_rpm` it compiles and creates correct rpm packages. But the problem is that when im running SWIG on a C++ source, it creates a `module.py` file that wraps the binary `_module.cpython32-mu.so` file, it is created with the `module_wrap.cpp` file, and it isnt copied to the `my_module` directory.

What I must write to the `setup.py` file to automatically copy the SWIG generated python modules?

And also I have another question: When I install the rpm package, I want that an executable will be created, in `/usr/bin` or so, to run the application (for example if the `my_module/my_module1.py` is the start script of the application then I can run in bash: `$ my_module1`).

Comment: Many thanks ... I needed to set the clang compiler flags ... this was the key that unlocked that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `build_py` (which copies python sources to the build directory) comes before `build_ext`, which runs SWIG.

You can easily subclass the build command and swap around the order, so `build_ext` produces `module1.py` before `build_py` tries to copy it.

```
from distutils.command.build import build

class CustomBuild(build):
    sub_commands = [
        ('build_ext', build.has_ext_modules), 
        ('build_py', build.has_pure_modules),
        ('build_clib', build.has_c_libraries), 
        ('build_scripts', build.has_scripts),
    ]

module1 = Extension('_module1', etc...)

setup(
    cmdclass={'build': CustomBuild},
    py_modules=['module1'],
    ext_modules=[module1]
)
```

However, there is one problem with this: If you are using setuptools, rather than just plain distutils, running `python setup.py install` won't run the custom build command. This is because the setuptools install command doesn't actually run the build command first, it runs egg_info, then install_lib, which runs build_py then build_ext directly.

So possibly a better solution is to subclass both the build and install command, and ensure build_ext gets run at the start of both.

```
from distutils.command.build import build
from setuptools.command.install import install

class CustomBuild(build):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command('build_ext')
        build.run(self)


class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command('build_ext')
        self.do_egg_install()

setup(
    cmdclass={'build': CustomBuild, 'install': CustomInstall},
    py_modules=['module1'],
    ext_modules=[module1]
)
```

It doesn't look like you need to worry about build_ext getting run twice.

Comment: Why not subclass `build_py`? Shameless plug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48942866/2321145

Answer (score 1):

It's not a complete answer, because I don't have the complete solution.
The reason why the module is not copied to the install directory is because it wasn't present when the setup process tried to copy it. The sequence of events is:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
file my_module.py (for module my_module) not found
file vcanmapper.py (for module vcanmapper) not found
running build_ext
```

If you run a second time `python setup.py install` it will do what you wanted in the first place. The official SWIG documentation for Python proposes you run first `swig` to generate the wrap file, and then run `setup.py install` to do the actual installation.

Answer (score 0):

[It looks like](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#extension-source-files) you have to add a `py_modules` option, e.g.:

```
setup(...,
  ext_modules=[Extension('_foo', ['foo.i'],
                         swig_opts=['-modern', '-I../include'])],
  py_modules=['foo'],
)
```

[Using rpm to Install System Scripts in Linux](http://www.logiqwest.com/TechnicalPapers/rpmScriptInstall.html), you'll have to modify your spec file. The `%files` section tells `rpm` where to put the files, which you can move or link to in `%post`, but such [can be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1509052/819417) defined in `setup.py` using:

```
options = {'bdist_rpm':{'post_install':'post_install', 'post_uninstall':'post_uninstall'}},
```

[Running Python scripts in Bash](http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/python/running.html) can be done with the usual first line as `#!/usr/bin/python` and executable bit on the file using `chmod +x filename`.

Comment: All you have written I already know. But my question was that how to automatically copy the SWIG generated `module.py` file to `my_module` directory. And also, I can run my scripts from bash. But the problem is that whan I install the rpm file, all my modules are installed to `/usr/lib/python3.2/` and I want to automatically make a link from selected module to `/usr/bin/module`.

Comment: Doesn't `py_modules` do that? You'll have to [modify your spec file](http://www.logiqwest.com/TechnicalPapers/rpmScriptInstall.html) for custom install locations, or use [Python's --post-install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511750/distutils-older-rpm-and-customized-spec-file).

Comment: that does not at all answer the question

Comment: @thias, not even including my comment?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman: the answer is hidden in the `py_modules` line in your code-example but without any explanation in the text of this answer. Instead, you elaborate on more general points, which is not needed here. I suggest, you clean up the answer a bit, such that others will find the answer, too.

Comment: @thias, 'twas the same logical line, but i've streamlined my answer.