# How to include SWIG execution in setup.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, swig, setuptools, distutils

I am trying to build a Python 3 module with a SWIG interface (let's say `example.i`) to some C++ utilities I have written (some classes, functions etc). I want to find a way to add the execution of SWIG inside the `setup.py` so that the user does not have to execute SWIG on their own (i.e. so that they don't have to run `swig -python -c++ example.i`).

More specifically, if the module is named `example`, I want the user to be able to simply run

```
pip install .
```

in the module directory and then be able to fire up a Python 3 interpreter and use the module:

```
$ python3
>>> import example
>>> my_object = example.MyClass()
>>> example.my_function(42)
...
```

Is there a way to do this in the `setup.py` file using either `distutils` or `setuptools`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html?highlight=swig#extension-source-files: *you can also include SWIG interface (.i) files in the list; the build_ext command knows how to deal with SWIG extensions: it will run SWIG on the interface file and compile the resulting C/C++ file into your extension.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setuptools+swig

Comment: @phd, Thanks for the good link to distutils -- but it says "This document is being retained solely until ..." ?? Would you know of a minimal but real example of `setup.py` with `setup( name="a-b", ext_modules = [Extension( "__x", ["a/b/x.i"]) ...` ?

Comment: See my second link above. For example https://stackoverflow.com/q/56562132/7976758